# push_back in std::list appears to be causing memory leaks

Tags: c++, list, pointers, memory-leaks

I have a std::list of Vectors (a very simple class for 2d vectors I wrote, not the std data structure.)  Here is that class:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
Vertex()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
Vertex(const Vertex &vert) {
    x = vert.x;
    y = vert.y;
}
Vertex(float getX, float getY)
{
    x = getX;
    y = getY;
}
Vertex & operator=(const Vertex &rhs)
{
    x = rhs.x;
    y = rhs.y;

    return *this;
}

float x, y;
};
```

I have several lists of these vectors, on which I perform operations like this (all these lists are declared as list:

```
if (vertList.size() != 0)
{
    Vertex newVert(x, y);

    if (loops == true)
    {
        if (axesList.size() != 0)
            axesList.pop_back();
    }

    Vertex normal = computeNormal(vertList.back(), newVert);
    axesList.push_back(normal);

    if (loops == true)
    {
        normal = computeNormal(newVert, vertList.front());
        axesList.push_back(normal);
    }
}

//actually adds the vertex
vertList.push_back(Vertex(x, y));
```

According to the leaks tool in Instruments, these lists are leaking memory (the responsible frame is listed as "std::__1::list>::push_back(Vertex const&)" )
As I don't have any instances declared with new, I am flummoxed by this leaked memory.  Does anyone have any idea what may be causing it?

Comment: I don't see you performing any dynamic memory allocation, so the leak would have to be in the `std::list` implementation, which is extremely unlikely. The other possibility is a false positive from your analyzer tool. Also, if that's really what your `Vertex` class looks like, there's no need to define a copy constructor/assignment operator. The compiler generated ones will suffice.

Comment: How/where is `vertList` created?  It's not dynamically allocated?  Is your program exiting normally - returning from `main()`?

Answer (score 3):

If `vertList` (or another `std::list`) exists and is non-empty when the program exits, the memory leak tool is probably complaining about its contents still being there. (Even though you don't use `new` yourself, `std::list` does internally.)

Otherwise, it is almost certainly a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

If your leak tool reports a leak from `std::list<>::push_back`, it means that some memory allocated in that function has not been deallocated or its (deallocation has not been detected) at the point when the leak detector summarizes its findings.

The most unlikely scenario would be that the `std::list` implementation you use itself is flawed and leaks memory under normal circumstances.
When analyzing how the detected leak can occur you have to take into account the possibility that the detection is actually a false positive. This can be the case if the leak detection tool considers the program as ended while there are some variables left.
This often is the case when the leak detection is a library tied into your program which records allocations and deallocations, and reports leaks when some global object in the library gets destroyed. If your list object is a global object or static member of a class, then it is prone to the *static initialization order fiasco*, meaning its destruction, including the release of the allocated memory could occur after the destruction of that memleak-reporting object.

However, if the tool monitors memory allocations and deallocations from "outside" the program, then two possible reasons for the leak come to mind:

1. The program exits abnormally, without unwinding the stack, calling the destructor of the list and thus deallocating the memory properly. Examples are explicit or implicit calls of `exit()`, `std::terminate` etc., for example due to multiple exceptions thrown.
2. The list is corrupted somehow, by stomping over the memory it owns and destroying its knowledge of the allocated elements. While things like that often lead to access violations a `memset(0)` is a good candidate to wreck things silently.